# Insert HTML content in WP Query at specific point

Tags: categories, theme-development, loop

I have a category page with an `if ( have_posts() ) : ?>` loop and would like to insert HTML content after the nth post.

I've done this previously with a WP_QUery using an `if( $query->current_post == 4 )` statement.

How can I achieve the same effect with a `have_posts` loop?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The global $wp_query is the default query you're working on when you use `have_posts()`, `the_post()` etc, so just add

```
global $wp_query;
if($wp_query->current_post == 4) echo "4!";
```

global might or might not be necessary (and is certainly only necessary once, so just add it before the while loop), it depends whether you're in the original template or in a template that has been included via a function call.